# Enum Throws "Is Not An Enum Type"

Tags: java, enums

I'm using both java *1.6.0_41* in production and dev builds. 
However, in production this line, namely *valueOf()*:

`List<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<Identifier>();`
`identifiers.add(Identifier.valueOf(key));`

throws **is not an enum**. Identifier is an enum.

Here's the stack trace.

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.core.datamodel.Identifier is not an enum type
    at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
<Break in method call trace. Could be due to JIT compiler inlining of method.>`

We use zkm as an obfuscator and so maybe that's the issue?

`public enum Identifier {FOO}`

I pass in a key string `FOO` and hope to get the `Identifier.FOO`

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: And code for identifier

Comment: What are valid enum values and what is the value of `key` when this happens?

Comment: Are you using some kind of an obfuscator for production builds?

Comment: The stack in obfuscated. I'm working on getting a non-obfuscated stack.

Comment: Perhaps you have a space at either the beginning or end of your String, which will be hard to detect in the exception message. Try `Identifier.valueOf(key.trim())` and see if it works.

Comment: I found that `is not an enum` is a message produced by the two-argument `valueOf()` in earlier versions of the `Enum` class, when the class parameter is not an enum class.  If the one-argument `valueOf()` calls the two-argument `valueOf()` and you're getting this message, that may mean the wrong class is getting passed, which makes me guess there's some sort of build problem where maybe you're using the wrong classpath or something.

Comment: @ajb, that seems likely. I'll investigate that.

Comment: But `"no enum const class"` is a totally different message.  That one might just be that the string is wrong.

Comment: @ajb, I removed that stack trace as it wasn't the exact stack and is misleading.

Comment: You should really show a minimal reproducible example and tell if you use any weird obfuscators, "optimizers" or do bytecode manipulation. My guess is that the enum class file is broken in some way.

Comment: @kapep You're right. Updating now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the obfuscator has renamed (or even removed) methods that internally need to be called by the enum class using reflections. Reflections won't work any more if the method has been renamed.

You should try to compile and run the code without the obfuscator. If this works, you can try to narrow down the cause by [excluding](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/excludeStatement.html) only the enum from getting obfuscated.

In particular I suspect that the enum's `values()` method may have been obfuscated. `valueOf` at some point looks for this method using `getMethod("values")`.

Comment: This is the issue. Enums are being obfuscated. Thanks!